# What is the correct way to use sql query in coldfusion function

Tags: mysql, function, coldfusion, sql-insert, coldfusion-2016

I have this code that will passed variable to function and insert it. But I'm getting error:

```
<cffunction name="insertSupplierPersonnel" output="false" access="public" returnType="struct">
    <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="email" type="string" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="office_phone" type="string" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="mobile_phone" type="string" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="designation" type="string" required="false" default="" />

    <cfset var res = '' />

    <cfquery datasource="#session.dsn_aset#" result="res">
        INSERT INTO `supplier_personnel_incharge` (
            `name`,
            `email`,
            `office_phone`,
            `mobile_phone`,
            `designation`
        )
        VALUES
        (
            cfargument.name,
            cfargument.email,
            cfargument.office_phone,
            cfargument.mobile_phone,
            cfargument.designation
        ) ;
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn res />
</cffunction>

<cfset res = insertSupplierPersonnel(name='#form.personnel_name#', email='#form.personnel_email#', office_phone='#form.personnel_office_phone#', mobile_phone='#form.personnel_mobile_phone#', designation='#form.personnel_designation#') />

<cfdump  var="#res#">
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

There's a problem with `cfargument.name`. What is the correct way to use `cfargument` for insert query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: either put `#` around or `cfqueryparam`

Comment: You run a serious risk of opening yourself up to SQL injection if you don't use `cfqueryparam`.

Answer (score 7):

First, the correct scope is `arguments`, not `cfargument`.  So, change this sort of thing:

```
cfargument.name,
```

to this:

```
arguments.name,
```

Next, you have to surround your variable names with pound signs to get the value of the variable, i.e. `#arguments.name#`.

Next, use query parameters, i.e. `<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.name#">`.  Among other things, they will escape special characters used in the SQL query syntax.

Comment: I would also recommend at least some basic error checking or sanitation before you insert the form values into your function. Or even just a simple `trim()` around the values to keep leading or trailing spaces out of your data.

Comment: Yep. @sg552 - Note, though `cfsqltype` was omitted for brevity, always specify one to avoid unexpected results in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize all of the correct answers and comments above. This would be your best practice:

- Function `returnType` should be "query", not "struct"
- If you specify a `default` value, CF recognizes the argument as "not required"
- Use `cfqueryparam` on all query parameters

Optional

- Use the `null` attribute of `cfqueryparam` to insert a `NULL` if there is no value given
- You don't need a trailing semi-colon at the end of the sql statement

---

```
<!---return type is query, not struct --->
<cffunction name="insertSupplierPersonnel" output="false" access="public" returnType="query">
    <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="true" />
    <!--- NOTE: If you specify a default value, CF recognizes the argument as "not required" --->
    <cfargument name="email" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="office_phone" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="mobile_phone" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="designation" type="string" default="" />

    <cfquery datasource="#session.dsn_aset#" result="local.data">
        INSERT INTO supplier_personnel_incharge (
            name, /*Unless your database column names are case-sensitive, you don't need quotation marks around the column names*/
            email,
            office_phone,
            mobile_phone,
            designation
        )
        VALUES
        (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(arguments.name)#">,
            /*insert NULL if there is no value given*/
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" null="#Not Len(trim(arguments.email))#" value="#trim(arguments.email)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" null="#Not Len(trim(arguments.office_phone))#" value="#trim(arguments.office_phone)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" null="#Not Len(trim(arguments.mobile_phone))#" value="#trim(arguments.mobile_phone)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" null="#Not Len(trim(arguments.designation))#" value="#trim(arguments.designation)#">,
        ) /*you don't need a trailing semi-colon*/
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn local.data />
</cffunction>

<cfset local.res = insertSupplierPersonnel(name='#form.personnel_name#',
    email='#form.personnel_email#', 
    office_phone='#form.personnel_office_phone#', 
    mobile_phone='#form.personnel_mobile_phone#', 
    designation='#form.personnel_designation#') />

<cfdump var="#local.res#">
```